# Validation for tr insert with alertbox (confirm.js) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to create a dynamic table that lets the user insert rows with textboxes and confirm the data/insert it on database by clicking a confirm button. The button works just fine, it inserts the table row on click, but i need a validation where the textboxes can't be blank and i can't make it work inside the function.

i've tried creating variables for the data on the textboxes, and used a simple if to confirm they are not empty, but the confirm button keeps adding the table rows without displaying the alert

```
$(function tableConfirm(){
    $(document).on('click','.btnConfirm', function(){
        var error=0;
        var campo1 = document.getElementById("campo1").value;
        var campo2 = document.getElementById("campo2").value;
        var campo3 = document.getElementById("campo3").value;
        var campo4 = document.getElementById("campo4").value;
//Html insertion
        var content='<tr><td><label class="checkContainer"><input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></td><td id="texto1">'+campo1+'</td><td id="texto2">'+campo2+'</td><td id="texto3">'+campo3+'</td><td id="texto4">'+campo4+'</td><td><button class="eliminar">X<!--</Button><<i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>--></td></tr>';
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();//this is to remove the textboxes before inserting the row data
        $('tbody',currentView).append(content);//this appends the row data
//Validation not working
        if(document.getElementById("texto1").value==""){
        $.alert({
            useBootstrap:false,
            columnClass:'small',
            title:'Error!',
            content:'you must fill all the blanks!',
            icon:'fas fa-exclamation-triangle',
            type:'red',
            typeAnimated:true,
            buttons:{
                tryAgain:{
                    text:'Ok',
                    btnClass: 'btn-red',
                    action: function(){
                    }
                }
            }
            });
        }
//This alertbox should only be displayed if the row has no blank spaces
        else
        $.alert({
            useBootstrap:false,
            columnClass: 'small',
            title: 'Success!',
            content: 'Task inserted!',
            type: 'green',
            icon:'fas fa-check-circle',
            typeAnimated: true,
            buttons: {
                tryAgain: {
                    text: 'Ok',
                    btnClass: 'btn-green',
                    action: function(){
                    }
                },
            }
        });

    });

});
```

I expect the code to alert the user when the textboxes aren't filled, but it always inserts the task and shows the respective alert.
Thank you for your time, I appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: texto1 has no **value** but **innerHTML**

Comment: So what variable should i compare in the if? I'm pretty confused

Answer (score 0):

a TD element has no `value` but `innerHTML` so repleace the following :

**wrong:**

```
if(document.getElementById("texto1").value=="")
```

**Correct:**

```
if(document.getElementById("texto1").innerHTML=="")
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, this did solve the problem of the alert box not showing if the textbox was blank, but the problem remains the same since the table row is still inserted

Comment: If you insert multiple rows then the ID will be repeated and you can not get new elements using ID. So you have to switch to **Class** instead of **ID** and perhaps a global counter to count how much rows you have inserted so far and pass the order of each button to the target function on click  to determine which button is being clicked. @Javier